# Call Postgresql function and populate class or dto

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring boot app with a postgresql db. I created a parametized function in the db, which I can call like this:

```
@Repository
public interface CapPlanningItemPerCapGroupRepository extends JpaRepository<CapPlanningItemPerCapGroupDto, Long> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM get_cap_planning_items(:year, :companyId, :plantId, :costAccTypeId)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<CapPlanningItemPerCapGroupDto> getCapPlanningItems(@Param("companyId") Long companyId, @Param("plantId") Long plantId,
                                                            @Param("year") int year, @Param("costAccTypeId") Long costAccTypeId);
}
```

The idea is to get the result mapped into a dto class (or a normal POJO). The above code snippet doesn't work of course (error: no managed type), because the dto class isn't an entity).

The question is: how can I map the result of the function to a POJO or dto class? In the POJO or dto I already have all the fields, which are the same as the returned columns from the function.

For me, it seems a valid requirement to call a function/stored procedure and map it to an existing class without any frills, but what I found on the net says the opposite.

What is the best practice in this case?

Comment: You can call a constructor in a jpa query, see https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/jpql-constructor-expression.html

Comment: And if you use JPA 2.1: https://thorben-janssen.com/call-stored-procedures-jpa/#:~:text=JPA%202.1%20introduced%20%40NamedStoredProcedureQuery%20which,the%20result%20of%20a%20query.